# GROUP BY custom aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to group by subquery via an aggregate below (I simplified the query to its most basic form, a `group by n` query).

But instead of using a max, I now need the following heuristic:

`bar` ranges from 0-2. I want to choose from 2,0,1 in that order. But I then want to original join on the **original** value of `bar`.

Can I write a custom aggregate function to return the right property? I'm a little lost on how the two would be combined.

```
SELECT 
    FOO.bar2
FROM
   FOO
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        FOO.id,
        custom_aggrgate(bar)
    FROM
        FOO                    
    GROUP BY
        FOO.id            
    ) b ON FOO.bar = inverse_of_custom_aggrgate(bar) -- get org. value of bar to join by
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of input values and the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be with `DISTINCT ON` and a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`:

I assume this is what you actually **want**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) bar2
FROM   foo
ORDER  BY id, CASE bar WHEN 2 THEN -1 ELSE bar END;
```

No need for custom aggregate function.
No need for another join.
No need for a function to invert the result of said custom aggregate function.

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

---

The **query in the question** is syntactically invalid and probably not what you want. With the syntax fixed, it might look like this:

```
SELECT FOO.bar2
FROM   FOO
INNER  JOIN (
    SELECT FOO.id, custom_aggrgate(bar) AS bar
    FROM   FOO                    
    GROUP  BY FOO.id            
    ) b ON FOO.bar = inverse_of_custom_aggrgate(b.bar);
```

But that's probably still nonsense. If `bar` isn't defined unique (which doesn't seem likely in your scenario), you get many duplicate rows. An equivalent for this dubious query would be:

```
SELECT f.bar2
FROM   foo f
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) bar
   FROM   foo
   ORDER  BY id, CASE bar WHEN 2 THEN -1 ELSE bar END
   ) b USING (bar);
```

I don't expect that's what you need.